# Evaluation of inverse of $tan$ integration

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $$\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{x\cos x}{1+\sin^2 x}dx$$

Try: Integration By parts

$$I = x\tan^{-1}(\sin x)\bigg|^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\tan^{-1}(\sin x)dx$$

$$I = \frac{\pi^2}{8}-\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\tan^{-1}(\sin x)dx$$

Let $$I(a)=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\tan^{-1}(a\sin x)dx$$

Then $$I'(a) = \int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{\sin x}{1+a^2\sin^2 x}dx =\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{\sin x}{(1+a^2)-a^2\cos^2 x}dx$$

$$I'(a) = -\frac{1}{2a\sqrt{1+a^2}}\ln\bigg|\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}+a}\bigg|$$

How can i solve it after that , Could some help me , Thanks

Comment: \begin{align}\ln\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1+a^2}-a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}+a}\bigg)&=-2\ln\bigg(\sqrt{1+a^2}+a\bigg)\\
&=-2\text{arcsinh }a\\
(\text{arcsinh }x)^\prime&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\\
\end{align} Not sure that the integral obtained is easiest to compute than the original one.